# Slick arrows button doesn't display between slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slick slider, here I don't know why it's doesn't display between the slider but instead, navigator buttons appear at the top and bottom of the slider like the screenshot below

[image]

here is my JS code :

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">next</button>',
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">prev</button>'
    });
```

and here my HTML code :

```
 <div class="slider multiple-items">
                        @foreach($data['related'] as $related)
                            @php 
                                $image = GlobalController::get_single_image($related->id);
                            @endphp
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <article class="entry">
                                    <div class="entry__img-holder">
                                        <a href="single-post.html">
                                            <div class="thumb-container thumb-75">
                                                <img data-src="{{ URL::to($image[0]->image) }}" src="{{ URL::to($image[0]->image) }}" class="entry__img lazyload" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="entry__body">
                                        <div class="entry__header">
                                          <h2 class="entry__title entry__title--sm">
                                            <a href="single-post.html">{{ strip_tags($related->description) }}</a>
                                          </h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </article>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
```

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: try removing `nextArrow` and `prevArrow`

Comment: the button is missing when i remove it ..

Comment: That means you are not included the css properly. try adding slick theme

Answer (score 1):

use css

Add slick.css in your

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
// Add the new slick-theme.css if you want the default styling
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in Chrome devtools network tab or console?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**: find the parent element which contains the buttons and images. For me, that element had this class:

```
class="slick-initialized slick-slider"
```

**CSS**: Add "display: flex;" (Also, if you want the images centered vertically, add "align-items: center;"), like so:

```
.slick-initialized.slick-slider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```